# Canvas, animate line to move up and down

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have created a horizontal line in `HTML5 Canvas`. I want to animate the line to move infinity up and down. Is it possible?

```
function horizontal_line() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(100, 100);
  context.lineTo(5000, 100);
  context.strokeStyle = "Green";
  context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Can you post here the relevant HTML, CSS, JS codes for your question please?

Comment: Refer [this](http://codular.com/animation-with-html5-canvas) and [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-start-and-stop-an-animation/) examples for your animation attempt. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an animation you will need to have a way to draw different frames, and in each frame you have to delete the previous one, calculate the new position of the line, and then draw the line again:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "Green";
var posY = 0;
var lineLength = 10;
var speed = 2;

function drawLine() {
 ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(10, posY);
  ctx.lineTo(10, posY+lineLength);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function moveLine () {
 posY += speed;
  
  if (posY < 0 || posY > canvas.height) {
   speed = speed * -1;
  }
}

function loop() {
 // clear old frame;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  moveLine();
  drawLine();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

In this example `requestAnimationFrame` is what provides you the frames you need, so the function `loop()` gets called over and over again. In there we clear the old frame with `clearRect()`, calculate the new position, and then we draw the new Line with `drawLine()`.